# Assigning a value to a global variable through input method

Tags: javascript

Good day. Have patience first of all since I am just a new enthusiast to Javascript and programming in general. The concern about my project is that I want to assign a value to a global variable through input method and run it through. I've tried, researched and nothing more work for me at this time. So I am asking anyone for ideas, how will it be possible. Your assistance will definitely help me in my learning process.

Initially, the code looks likes this: Here the global variable numItems is defined by 30. That variable numItems is also mentioned within two other functions below. What I want to do is change that number through input method. I've tried...

```
numItems = 30;
var xvalue = [];
var yvalue = [];
for (var i=0; i < numItems; i++) {
xvalue.push(i % 9);    yvalue.push((i % 9)+1);      
}

followed by several functions....
```

---

This is my try, but it seems this is not working... Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
numItems = document.getElementById("numInput");
numItems.addEventListener("input", whatValue);

function whatValue() {
var num = parseFloat(numItems.value);
document.getElementById("numInput") = num;
}

var xvalue = [];
var yvalue = [];
for (var i=0; i < numItems; i++) {
xvalue.push(i % 9);    yvalue.push((i % 9)+1);      
}

followed by several functions....
```

---

Here is the whole code when I applied Michael's suggestions below: It works, but my concern now are the undefined variables in the output--->  undefined + undefined     or undefined - undefined

```
<body>
<input id="numInput">
<select id="processMath">
  <option value="add">Addition</option>
  <option value="sub">Subtraction</option>
</select>
<button onclick="newExercise()">New Exercise</button>
<button onclick="createExercise()">Create Exercise</button>
<div id="tableOne"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
numItems = document.getElementById("numInput");
numItems.addEventListener("input", whatValue);

function whatValue() {
numItems = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numInput").value);
}

xvalue = [];
yvalue = [];
for (var i=0; i<numItems ; i++) {
xvalue.push(i % 9);    yvalue.push((i % 9)+1);      
}

function tableOne (operator) {
var valtp = '';
var spc = '<table border="1" width="80%"><tr>';
i = 0;
while (i < numItems ) {
a = xvalue[i];
b = yvalue[i];
spc += '<td align="right">'+a;
if (operator == 'add') { spc += '<br>+ '+b; valtp = a+b; }
if (operator == 'sub') { spc += '<br>- '+b; valtp = a-b; }
spc += '<br>_____';
i++;  
if ((i % 5) == 0) { spc += '</tr><tr>'; }
}  
spc += '</tr></table>';
return spc;
}

function createExercise() {
var a = 0;  var b = 0;  var spc = '';
var spc = '';
var sel = document.getElementById('processMath').value;
switch (sel) {
case 'add' : spc += tableOne(sel); break;
case 'sub' : spc += tableOne(sel); break;
}
document.getElementById('tableOne').innerHTML = spc;
}

function makeRandom() {
return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5);
}

function newExercise() {
xvalue.sort(makeRandom);
yvalue.sort(makeRandom);
}
</script>
```

Comment: "is not working" is a poor description of the problem you are having. Any errors in your developer tools console? Which part of the code doesn't produce the result you expect? What do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: `document.getElementById("numInput") = num;` is never going to work if the element with the id=numInput is an `<input>` element. If it was of that type, you'd need to use the `.value` member, as in `document.getElementById("numInput").value = num;` - same goes for any other instance in your code that you wish to get/set the value an input holds.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood you, it looks like your `whatValue()` function is trying to change the input value, instead of changing the `numItems` variable, but it's failing on both counts.

```
function whatValue() {
  var num = parseFloat(numItems.value);
  document.getElementById("numInput") = num;
}
```

Should be:

```
function whatValue() {
  numItems = parseFloat(document.getElementById("numInput").value);
}
```

Now, your numItems variable should change every time numInput changes.

But, even though numItems changes, it won't make the rest of your code run again. So your two arrays will still look like they did when numItems was 30.

Comment: Your input works. But my concern now is I have undefined variables in the output... like undefined + undefined   or undefined - undefined... see the whole code above...